# Post Delay Method - Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, postdelayed

I used postedDelayed method to refresh my Activity, which works fine. But the problem is that even when I press the Back button postdelayed method call back the previous activity..

//handler for 30000 milli-secs  post delay refreshment of the activity

```
mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
               dostuff();

        }
            }, 30000);
    }

protected void dostuff() {
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();startActivity(intent);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "refreshed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(null);
        }

protected void onStop() {
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(null);
        super.onStop();
    }
```

Comment: Please post your code ........to check the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `removeCallbacks(runnable)` method of the handler using which you are calling `postDelayed()` method. For example, if you used:

```
mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, mTime)
```

for refreshing the activity, then use

```
mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable)
```

in `onPause()` method of the activity.

Comment: It is still making the Application crash and i am not getting any logs for this.

Answer (score 0):

Make a sign of boolean in your postdelayed method. Init the sign as true,when the activity is finnished , set the value of sign as false.

Comment: Your answer's not clear. Perhaps a code sample would make this easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this piece of code to run after a 3 sec delay.

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {          
    @Override
    public void run() {

        // run your code here    

    }
}, 3000);
```